# How to customize tmux 'last window marker"?

Tags: tmux

By default Tmux display `-` after window title to denote last visited window. Is there a way to customize this marker and set it to custom symbol? Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`man 1 tmux` says:

> By default, the window list shows the index, name and (if any) flag of the windows present in the current session in ascending numerical order. It may be customised with the `window-status-format` and `window-status-current-format` options. The flag is one of the following symbols appended to the window name:
>
> ```
> Symbol    Meaning
> *         Denotes the current window.
> -         Marks the last window (previously selected).
> #         Window is monitored and activity has been detected.
> !         A bell has occurred in the window.
> ~         The window has been silent for the monitor-silence interval.
> M         The window contains the marked pane.
> Z         The window's active pane is zoomed.
> ```

About `set-window-option window-status-format`:

> `window-status-format string`
>   Set the format in which the window is displayed in the status line window list. […] The default is `#I:#W#F`.

Then under `FORMATS` you learn `#F` means "window flags". I have found no trace of any ability to change symbols associated with flags directly. Still you can use this:

> In addition, the first line of a shell command's output may be inserted using `#()`.

This means you can use `tr` or `sed` to change `-` into something else. You may be alarmed by this:

> When constructing formats, `tmux` does not wait for `#()` commands to finish; instead, the previous result from running the same command is used, or a placeholder if the command has not been run before.

Still in my tests simple replacements with `tr` or `sed` seem to just work immediately, so probably there's nothing to be worry about. From within `tmux` run this:

```
tmux set-window-option -g window-status-format "#I:#W#(printf '%%s\n' '#F' | tr '-' '<')"
```

or this:

```
tmux set-window-option -g window-status-format "#I:#W#(printf '%%s\n' '#F' | sed 's/-/</')"
```

I recommend `tr` because it's simpler and smaller than `sed`, it should perform better (if it matters). But if you want to replace `-` with some multi-character<sup>*</sup> string then `sed` is your tool. Example:

```
tmux set-window-option -g window-status-format "#I:#W#(printf '%%s\n' '#F' | sed 's/-/<--/')"
```

Notes:

- `%%` instead of `%` is because of the `tmux` parser.
- `tmux set-window-option window-status-format …` (without `-g`) specifies format for a single window; this will take precedence over the global format for this particular window.
- There's also `window-status-current-format` which specifies format used when the window is the current window. The "last window" flag obviously never applies to the current window, but if you want to customize flags that may apply then you need to alter `window-status-current-format` as well.
- A line to add to `/etc/tmux.conf` or `~/.tmux.conf` is like:

  ```
  set-window-option -g window-status-format "#I:#W#(printf '%%s\n' '#F' | tr '-' '<')"
  ```

---

<sup>*</sup>Or rather multi-byte. Compare [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228570/108618).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know when this was added but you can perform regex replacement with tmux format which makes it more simple to achieve this. From the manpage:

```
A prefix of the form ‘s/foo/bar/:’ will substitute ‘foo’ with ‘bar’ throughout.
The first argument may be an extended regular expression and a final argument may be ‘i’ to ignore case, for example:
 ‘s/a(.)/\1x/i:’ would change ‘abABab’ into ‘bxBxbx’.
```

So for your use case you can perform replacement on the `window_flags` variable content like this:

```
set-window-option -g window-status-format "  #{s/-/>>/:window_flags} #I #W"
```