# Z appears before and after the tmux window name

Tags: tmux

For some reason, occasionally, in the tabline of the tmux an uppercase Z appears at the right side of the window name and leftside of before window number, so the window name looks like this:

Z11:bashZ
Z12:windownameZ

I have no issues with this behavior. But want to understand if this some behavior which can be used for my advantage.

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#STATUS_LINE) [emphasis mine]:

> By default, the window list shows the index, name and (if any) flag of the windows present in the current session in ascending numerical order. It may be customised with the `window-status-format` and `window-status-current-format` options. The flag is one of the following symbols appended to the window name:
>
> ```
> Symbol    Meaning
> *         Denotes the current window.
> -         Marks the last window (previously selected).
> #         Window activity is monitored and activity has been detected.
> !         Window bells are monitored and a bell has occurred in the window.
> ~         The window has been silent for the monitor-silence interval.
> M         The window contains the marked pane.
> Z         The window's active pane is zoomed.
> ```

This would explain the trailing `Z` in `Z12:windownameZ`, but not the leading one. You're probably using a *customized* format; if so, then these `Z`s may mean anything. Compare this question: [*How to customize tmux 'last window marker"?*](https://superuser.com/q/1486785/432690)

Analyze the output of `tmux show-options -Aw | grep 'window-status.*-format'`. Maybe your customized format simply uses `#{window_flags}` (or `#F`) twice and each `Z` means "zoomed".